# C++ Error with the operator* in a custom iterator for a b-tree

Tags: c++, iterator, operator-overloading, b-tree

I'm getting the following error when trying to return the value using the operator*() in my custom iterator.

```
 error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'char&' from a temporary of type 'char'
```

If anyone is able to help me out, that would be great!

The specifics of the code is as follows:

Test code:

```
  for(btree<char>::iterator itr = tree.begin(); itr != tree.end(); ++itr) {

    cout << *itr << " "; // <- this line complains about the * operator.
  }
```

The operator*() code:

```
template <typename T> typename btree_iterator<T>::reference btree_iterator<T>::operator*() const {

  return pointee_->value(); // <- this line is where the error above is produced from.
}
```

pointee_ from the btree_iterator class is a private variable defined as follows:

```
btree_node<T>* pointee_;
```

reference is typefef'ed as the following in the btree_iterator class:

```
  typedef T&       reference;
```

value() is defined in the btree_node class as follows:

```
T value() const;

// function definition.
template <typename T> T btree_node<T>::value() const { return value_; }
```

value is initially stored into a btree_node via it's constructor as follows:

```
template <typename T> btree_node<T>::btree_node(const T& elem) : value_(elem), nextCont_(NULL), prevCont_(NULL), nextNode_(NULL), prevNode_(NULL) {}
```

Please let me know if i missed including any crucial information, and apologies if i did!

Based on the error, it sounds like I'm trying to return a reference to a local variable. The iterator itself may be local, but the value that it is returning shouldn't be, since the node constructor originally takes in a reference, and stores that into the node.

Thanks in advance, and regards!

Comment: Instead of splitting all the functions out, it really would be nice if it were just in one block ready to be copy-pasted into a compiler - see [this](http://sscce.org/) for more info.

Comment: Try returning a constant reference instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to use a reference to a temporary variable

```
template <typename T> T btree_node<T>::value() const { return value_; }
                     ^^^
```

This returns a temporary copy of `value_`.

```
template <typename T> typename btree_iterator<T>::reference btree_iterator<T>::operator*() const {
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  return pointee_->value(); // <- this line is where the error above is produced from.
}
```

This returns a reference to that temporary copy. You most likely want `value()` to return a reference, but this is up to you - a reference allows clients of your `btree` to alter the contents. Especially if the tree is ordered based upon the value of the node, you may not want to allow this. Have a think how this is relevant to your design.

Comment: Thanks Ayjay, this seems to be my problem! I'll mark the problem solved once i figure it out in my head :)

Answer (score 1):

`pointee_->value()` returns a values which is basically a fresh copy. Hence this value is local in `operator*` and you can't return a reference to that.

I'd recommend doing it just like most containers do, i.e. having both, `iterator` and `const_iterator`, whereas const_iterator returns a const reference and iterator returns a reference. The same principle applies to `value()`. Have versions returning a ref and a const ref.

If you ever want to work on copies, you can create them from the reference in client code. If you don't want to allow chanign the values, simply drop (or make private, or whatever) the non-const parts. It think it also fits what people using your btree expect:

Iterators do not make copies somewhere but you iterator over the data inside teh data  structure. If you want copies, you can make them.

Comment: Thanks b.buchhold for the further clarification! Just a quick question: When you say to have 2 versions of value() too, do you mean overload one to have a return type of const T&, and one with a return type of just T&? It seems like the compile doesn't let me overload in this way. Also, yes i will be having a const and non-const iterator :)

Comment: You will also make one of them a const member function, i.e. const T& value() const; vs T& value(); which should be valid overloading